# Adding the results into one list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this problem it may look easy but I just can't do it, I am working on a web scraping project and now I am scraping a list of keywords so my code prints the results just like this.

```
Kids Wear Shop
Plastic Children Toys 
Balloon
Costumes
Montessori Toys
```

all I want to do to store these results in a single list I tried to append them to a list but it stores every single line in a list of its own.

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for div in  soup.find_all('div', class_='keywords content-div'):
    for span in div.find_all('span', class_='keyword key-content'):
         for a in span.find_all('a'):
             print(a.text)
```

Comment: can you show us what you did?

Comment: What is "it" thats doing the storing?

Comment: Is this really what happens when you do `print(lst)`? In this case this seems more like a large concatenated string instead of a nested list. Please show the exact output.

Comment: I want the output to be stored in a single list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_all()` returns a list of all results. So if there is only one found it will return a list which contains that one result. If you know there is only one value then use `find()` instead. You can then append that single value:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
lst = []
for div in  soup.find_all('div', class_='keywords content-div'):
    for span in div.find_all('span', class_='keyword key-content'):
         lst.append(span.find('a').text)
print(lst)
```

Or if there are indeed multiple `a`s possible you can just append everything to the list:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
lst = []
for div in  soup.find_all('div', class_='keywords content-div'):
    for span in div.find_all('span', class_='keyword key-content'):
         for a in span.find_all('a'):
             lst.append(a.text)
print(lst)
```

Or you concatenate the lists in every step:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
lst = []
for div in  soup.find_all('div', class_='keywords content-div'):
    for span in div.find_all('span', class_='keyword key-content'):
         lst += [a.text for a in span.find_all('a')]
print(lst)
```